# Regex replace space with

Tags: regex, content-grabber

I have a block of code that is scraping a very poorly formatted price.  I want to just use regular expressions to clean it up.
They are sending

```
$ 3 58
```

I want to remove the $ and space and replace the space in between dollars and cents with a . so I get:

```
3.58
```

I can get rid of the $ and leading space but I am really stuck on the substitution. 
I know that

```
  Regex (.*) returns everything
  Regex \ (.*) returns '3 58'
```

But what I really want is

```
  3.58
```

I am trying to do this inside of a program called content grabber so all I have access to is the regular expressions.

Comment: Try `(\d+) (\d+)` and `return $1.$2`

Comment: [Did it work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032982/3832970)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capturing parentheses.

\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)

\1.\2

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you need is to [**capture**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) two space-separated digit chunks and use a command that will join the groups with a dot:

```
(\d+) (\d+)
return $1.$2
```

Since the `return` command just returns what was matched, there is no need to match anything else int the input.

The `(\d+) (\d+)` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 (`$1`) one or more digits, then a space is matched (`\s+` can be used to match 1+ whitespace chars) and then `(\d+)` pattern again matches and captures into Group 2 (`$2`) one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(' $ 1 20'.replace(/[^0-9\ .]/g, '').trim().replace(/\ /g, '.'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `$ 3 58` you could match what you want to remove in the replacement and capture what you want to keep.

Match a dollar sign `\$` and then match one or more whitespace characters `\s+` and capture in a group one or more digits `(\d+)`

In the replacement use group1 . group2. For example `$1.$2`

[`\$\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/4UsJdN/1)